# What happens if we restrict inputs in Separation and Replacement axioms to definable sets?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, cardinal-characteristics

If we replace the axiom of Foundation by

**Foundation schema:** if $\varphi(x)$ is a formula in which "$x$" occurs free and only free, and in which "$y$" doesn't occur, whose free variables other than "$x$" are among $\vec{p}$, and if $\varphi(x/y)$ is the formula resulting from replacing every occurrence of "$x$" in $\varphi(x)$ by "$y$"; then: $$\forall \vec{p} \, \bigl(\exists x \, (\varphi(x)) \to \exists x: \varphi(x) \land \forall y \, (\varphi(x/y) \to y \not \in x)\bigr)$$

Now, we write the axioms of Separation and Replacement in naive form, that is in the form $\forall x_1, \cdots , x_n \exists x: x= \{y \mid \varphi\}$, where "$y,x_1,\cdots,x_n$" are the sole free variables of $\varphi$, we'll consider each such expression as basically expressing an $n$-ary function with *inputs* (arguments) $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ and output (value)  $x$.

Now, the plan is to restrict the inputs of the axioms of Separation and Replacement to parameter free definable sets. We'll denote the so restricted schemas by Separation$^{\sf d}$ and Replacement$^{\sf d}$. Formally:

**Separation$^{\sf d}$ + Replacement$^{\sf d}$:** If $\varphi_1, \cdots, \varphi_n$ are formulas in which "$y$" only occurs free, and having no free variables other than "$y$"; and if $\psi, \phi$ are formulae whose free variables are "$y,x_1,\cdots,x_n$" and "$z,u,x_1, \cdots , x_n$" respectively; then:

$$\forall x_1, \cdots, \forall x_n :(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n x_i=\{y \mid \varphi_i \}) \to\\  \exists x: x= \{y  \mid y \in x_n \land \psi\} \\   \exists x: x= \{y \mid \exists z \in x_n  \forall u \, (\phi \leftrightarrow u=y)\} $$

Keep the other axioms of $\sf ZFC$ in their full forms, i.e. the usual form of Extensionality and Choice, and the biconditional form of Pairing, Union, Powerset, and Infinity (i.e., existence of a set of all von Neumann naturals).

This is a follow up on the subject presented at posting titled "[If parameters in ZFC are restricted to definable sets, can existence of uncountable sets be proven?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467823/95347)", but here I sought the least restrictive approach.

> I personally don't know if this theory can prove existence of uncountable sets? Or even if it can prove full $\sf ZFC$? It might? But, for the time being, what can be known of the strength of this theory? Can it prove Cantor's theorem? Which $n$-order arithmetic is interpretable here? I think $\sf PA$ is. But, if existence of uncountable sets is not provable, then which fragment of 2nd order arithmetic it clearly interprets?